# what's the difference between list(temp) or [temp]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting some errors using list like it works when i try this

```
new_list=new_list+[temp]
```

but it didn't work when i use list(temp)

```
new_list=new_list+list(temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error because you are trying to make a list with an integer:

```
temp = 1
print(list(temp))
```

output:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The **list()** constructor returns a mutable sequence list of elements. The iterable argument is optional. You can provide any sequence or collection (such as a string, list, tuple, set, dictionary, etc). If no argument is supplied, an empty list is returned.

The example below works fine because you are putting an integer inside a list:

```
temp = 1
print([temp])
```

output:

```
[1]
```

The list has been constructed using a pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

According to python official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), list object can be constructed in several ways:

> - Using a pair of square brackets to denote the empty list: []
> - Using square brackets, separating items with commas: [a], [a, b, c]
> - Using a list comprehension: [x for x in iterable]
> - Using the type constructor: list() or list(iterable)

So, `[]` is syntax literal and `list()` is  builtin constructor function. For the latter, the argument accepted is iterable (If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list, `[]`), that's the reason `list(1)` throws TypeError.